# How to change Code style for adding space around parameter within an IntelliJ environment?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I accidentally changed something within the code style in my PhpStorm. Now, when I press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F</kbd> for formatting, a space is placed in front and after parameters in a method call within a function.

[image]

How can I change this back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Editor > PHP > Spaces > Within, see if "Function declaration parantheses" or "Function call parantheses" are checked.

Answer (score 0):

In tab "Spaces", option "Within", desactive "Method declaration parentheses".